# Programmatically breaking search distance into two parts in PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a query which for each address location (ad), searches the nearest streets (st) in a radius of 50 meters and return (260 rows) selected streets with respective address locations. Table 'ad' contains 87 rows, while 'st' contains 16,060 rows. The execution time is 61 milli-seconds. The code is below:

```
SELECT  
      ad.gid As address_id,
      ST_AsText(ad.geom) As address_locations,
      ST_AsText(st.geom) As selected_streets
FROM ad
Left JOIN st ON ST_DWithin(ad.geom, st.geom, 50)
ORDER BY  ad.gid, St_Distance(ad.geom, st.geom);
```

Now, I would like to programmatically break this query such that: for each address location the search is first performed in a radius of 30 meters, if streets are found select them and then expand the search distance up to 50 meters for those not in 30 meters radius. How to do that?

Comment: It's 61 milliseconds why do you want to optimize that?

Comment: I am trying to enhance the search criteria somehow (as mentioned above). Execution time is OK for me for now however, this would be significant when i would test the above query for larger tables (for example: millions of rows).

Comment: so why not just search for 50 meters and sort by nearest?

Comment: That I am already doing in the above code using 'Order By' clause. I could also use ST_Distance() to visualize the distance from address to each street but the search parameters needs to be broken down in two parts instead of one i.e., first 30 meters and then 50 meters. I am aware that this may affect the performance time.